# How can I switch this audio jack, using its own mechanical switches, without creating feedback?

Tags: transistors, audio

I've spent a few hours inside my car radio and I've found that when I short a hidden pin called AUX-ON to VCC, I can pipe music right into the it and it's treated like a regular AUX input. Great success.

Now, I have a switched jack that I'd like to use to short VCC to AUX-ON whenever I plug in a cable. The jack I'm using is Radio Shack 274-0246, the diagram is below. I can't figure out any way to do this without having the potential of grounding the audio to the vehicle ground (which could, I assume, distort quality) or without having the potential of sending 12v back through the audio cable into the phone. I know there MUST be a way to do this with a semiconductor or two, but I don't even know where to start. All I know is I need to pass current from pin 2 to 3 (or 4 to 5) and when that current stops (the jack mechanically separates the contacts when plugged in) then VCC can go to AUX.

[image]

**EDIT:** I forgot to mention, the unit is expecting balanced inputs, however.. I don't think I've ever seen an ipod or phone with balanced outputs. Should that be taken into consideration with this circuitry?

Comment: Consumer equipment is off-topic. question should be closed.

Comment: This question is not about consumer equipment. It's about how I can sense the interruption of power and use that to trigger something else... I mentioned that it's in a radio just to provide some context, the radio has nothing to do with the question.

Comment: Why can't you just connect AUX-ON to VCC all of the time?

Comment: I am going to have to disagree with Leon, although this started as a consumer electronics question, the actual question here is "How can I short 2 contacts when I plug in a headphone jack" This is something I could see being a common question for many electronics projects. It is a little on the broad side, but I think it is acceptable.

Comment: @Cybergibbons - Because then the radio doesn't work.  These switching jack diagrams were (and still occasionally are) very confusing to me, and I agree with Kellenjb that this is a good question.

Comment: @KevinVermeer - how do we know the radio doesn't work like that? I can't see anything detailed in the post.

Comment: @Cybergibbons - You're right, we don't *know* that.  But that's a typical design, it's how most of these interfaces work.  It might even be standardized somewhere.

Comment: I didn't mention it, but yes, when in AUX mode the radio and CD won't work. The only way to switch out of it is by disconnecting the contacts. The radio won't even turn off with power running through!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't even need a semiconductor.

[image: Audio jack insertion detect]

In this circuit, when no jack is connected, GPIO will be pulled down to (almost) ground R4. When you insert the jack, R4 becomes disconnected, and R2 weakly pulls GPIO up to AVDD.

In your case you'd have VCC instead of AVDD. And you'd have AUX-ON instead of GPIO.

Comment: I've adapted your drawing to what I'm trying to do: http://i.imgur.com/CYTjp.png - is that set up correctly? And if so, how does that stop current from VCC to AUX at all - all that's between them is a resistor? Also, what does a capacitor do in this case? Thanks a ton!

Comment: @kavisiegel - The resistor won't stop the current, but it will reduce it to almost nothing. The capacitors will also block any DC voltage from the jack reaching the phone.

Comment: Did I mix up GND and AUX in my drawing? I just can't visualize how the current would flow here, heh. In a normal state, with nothing plugged in, I see the following circuit: (VCC) -> (J1 pin 11) -> (J1 pin 3) -> (R4) -> (GND) AND (VCC) -> (R2) -> (AUX) With the jack plugged in, VCC only goes to R2 and AUX, not ground. Am I misinterpreting?

Comment: @kavisiegel - GND shouldn't be connected to AUX when the jack is plugged in. You want AUX to be pulled up to VCC don't you?

Comment: That's correct, yes. If my adapted drawing looks correct, could you perhaps explain how it works a bit? Because I just can't grasp how VCC connects to AUX in any way except for through R2. It seems like all the switching is done on GND? (Side question - Is R3 actually doing anything?)

Comment: Also - about the caps, does that mean they pretty much act as diodes? Would an isolation transformer also be appropriate there? Half because I'm worried about what happens if I'm listening to a device that I'm also charging at the same time, and half because I really want to picture how this works!

Comment: @kavisiegel - join me in chat

Comment: Oh boy! (1) Note that although you have the capacitor there, the ring of your jack is at VCC potential when nothing is plugged in, and so briefly, as you insert the plug, 12V can be present in your cable. (2) 100 uF is way overblown for adequate bass response. Remember, the bigger the cap, the longer it takes to charge. For 100 uF to make sense, the impedance of the input you're going into would have to be ridiculously low. Chances are it isn't. A 0.8 uF coupling cap rolls off only -3dB at 20Hz into a 10K impedance.

Comment: @Rocketmagnet It seems I missed you in chat - perhaps tomorrow!

Comment: @Kaz - Noted, I'll use smaller caps. It took me a minute to understand what you were saying about VCC getting through the cable, but after staring at the jack with a cable in it for a minute, I got it. Could this risk be eliminated with a big resistor and NPN transistor?